# c# search a text using c# but the answer is next to the keyword

Tags: c#

i have a string and i need to search.

for example i need to search the `"Exif Byte Order"`
keyword and the output is the whole word next to it

```
Little-endian
```

how can i do this? i tried searching but the solutions but i can't find a problem similar to mine.

this is the string

```
File    File Name   NHD-and-Chronicling-America_04.jpg
File    Directory   C:/Users/Desktop/images
File    File Size   65 kB
File    File Modification Date/Time 2016:08:04 14:16:37-07:00
File    File Access Date/Time   2016:08:10 13:38:40-07:00
File    File Creation Date/Time 2016:08:10 13:38:40-07:00
File    File Permissions    rw-rw-rw-
File    File Type   JPEG
File    File Type Extension jpg
File    MIME Type   image/jpeg
File    Exif Byte Order Little-endian (Intel, II)
File    Image Width 274
File    Image Height    498
File    Encoding Process    Baseline DCT, Huffman coding
File    Bits Per Sample 8
File    Color Components    3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using *Linq*:

```
  string source = ...

  string key = "Exif Byte Order";  

  var result = source
    .Split(new char[] {'\r', '\n'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(line => {
       int index = line.IndexOf(key, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

       return index < 0 ? null : line.Substring(index + key.Length).Trim();
     })
    .FirstOrDefault(line => line != null);

  // Little - endian(Intel, II)
  Console.Write(result);
```

If you want to obtain `Little-endian` exactly, you can try *regular expressions* instead of simple `line.IndexOf`:

```
 var result = source
   .Split(new char[] {'\r', '\n'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries )
   .Select(line => Regex.Match(line, "(?<=" + Regex.Escape(key) + @"\s*)([\w\s-/]+)"))
   .FirstOrDefault(match => match.Success)
  ?.Value
  ?.Trim();
```

Comment: the output is : Little-endian (Intel, II)

not the whole word next to it. but im going to split it and get the first word. thank you sir

Comment: @codequery18: you have to define what *whole word* is. Now it's letters, digits (`\w`), white spaces (`\w`) and `-`; I've added `/` (see my edit), so now it should return `image/jpeg` for `MIME Type`

Answer (score 0):

Split() your string by search string. You'll get a string that starts with what you want. Split that too by a space or whatever you want.